# how to unindent slim code in emacs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs, slim-lang

I am using slim with emacs for development. I am able to indent blocks of slim code by just marking the block and then pressing tab.

However how do I unindent a whole block back? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Murtaa

Comment: What exactly do you mean by unindent? Remove all whitespace from the front of each line, or moving the whole block left by a fix amount of spaces/tabs?

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the reply. I am would like to move the whole block left by a fix amount of spaces/tabs, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Select the code block, then do <kbd>C-u - 4 C-x TAB</kbd> to unindent the marked region by 4 spaces.

- <kbd>C-u</kbd> allows to specify a [prefix argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) to the following indent command
- <kbd>- 4</kbd> gives the amount of indentation (-4). Since the number is negative, you're indenting to the left.
- <kbd>C-x TAB</kbd> indents the region by the given amount.

This answer might also be interesting to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624677/261142

Comment: thanks for the reply. When I tried the above I got this message `This buffer cannot use 'imenu-default-create-index-function'.

Comment: Also I am using slim-mode which lets me indent 2 spaces with just a TAB.

Comment: Which slim-mode are you using? I just tested the above method with the slim-mode from here: https://github.com/minad/emacs-slim and it works as expected.