# emacs24 backtab is undefined , how to define this shortcut-key

Tags: emacs, emacs24

How to define `<backtab>` short key in emacs24 ?

I had found some solution,

like:

- http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/daveg/Info/backtab-howto.txt
- [Emacs Shift-Tab to left shift the block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249955/emacs-shift-tab-to-left-shift-the-block)

but it isn't work for me.

---

In the end:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<backtab>") 'un-indent-by-removing-4-spaces)
(defun un-indent-by-removing-4-spaces ()
  "remove 4 spaces from beginning of of line"
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (save-match-data
      (beginning-of-line)
      ;; get rid of tabs at beginning of line
      (when (looking-at "^\\s-+")
        (untabify (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))
      (when (looking-at "^    ")
        (replace-match "")))))
```

**worked** for me !!!

thanks @Drew and @lawlist.

Comment: Be sure that `<backtab>` is in fact the key you want to bind.  The key labeled `Tab` on your keyboard, when pressed with modifier key `Shift`, can produce different soft keys for different keyboards and for different versions of Emacs. If, after trying the solution provided by @lawlist, it does not seem to work, check what `C-h k` says for `Shift` + `Tab`. It might not be `<backtab>`.  It might be `<S-tab>` of `<S-iso-lefttab>`.  Whatever key it tells you is the one you want to bind.